AOSP Emulator Offline
enter image description hereI am new into AOSP and trying to learn the same. I have started the emulator using
emulator

command and I can see it.
However, when I issue
adb devices

command, it shows offline.
I tried to kill the adb server and start it again too though it doesn't helps.
When I tried with
netstat 

command, I can see only emulator is listening to the correct port.
Below one was the lunch command
lunch aosp_cf_x86_64_phone-trunk_staging-userdebug

I am using HP Omen Gaming computer with 64GB RAM and 1 TB SSD. Processor is 13th Generation Intel® Core™ i9 processor. Operating system is Ubuntu 24.0
Lunch command log
Android emulator version 35.3.8.0 (build_id 12560773) (CL:N/A)
INFO         | Graphics backend: gfxstream
INFO         | Changing default hw.initialOrientation to portrait

INFO         | Increasing RAM size to 2048MB
INFO         | Checking system compatibility:
INFO         |   Checking: hasSufficientDiskSpace
INFO         |      Ok: Disk space requirements to run avd: `<build>` are met.
INFO         |   Checking: hasSufficientHwGpu
INFO         |      Ok: Hardware GPU requirements to run avd: `<build>` are passed.
INFO         |   Checking: hasSufficientSystem
INFO         |      Ok: System requirements to run avd: `<build>` are met.
WARNING      | encryption is off
WARNING      | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
INFO         | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_new_posture_requested(int) ((null):0, (null))

INFO         | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_dismiss_posture_selection_dialog() ((null):0, (null))

INFO         | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_new_resizable_requested(PresetEmulatorSizeType) ((null):0, (null))

INFO         | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_dismiss_resizable_dialog() ((null):0, (null))

INFO         | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_sleep_timer_done() ((null):0, (null))

INFO         | Warning: QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_unfold_timer_done() ((null):0, (null))

INFO         | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-syammohan/emu-crash-35.3.8.db, detection is enabled for process: 5692
WARNING      | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
WARNING      | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
WARNING      | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
WARNING      | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
WARNING      | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
WARNING      | Your GPU drivers may have a bug. Switching to software rendering.
library_mode swangle_indirect gpu mode swangle_indirect
WARNING      | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
INFO         | Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
I1030 08:50:56.946597    5692 opengles.cpp:285] android_startOpenglesRenderer: gpu info
I1030 08:50:56.946613    5692 opengles.cpp:286] 
INFO         | Raised nofile soft limit to 4096.
INFO         | HealthMonitor disabled.
INFO         | initIcdPaths: ICD set to 'swiftshader', using Swiftshader ICD
INFO         | Setting ICD filenames for the loader = /home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/vk_swiftshader_icd.json:/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/vk_swiftshader_icd.json
INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so]

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so]: not found in map, open for the first time

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so] (posix): begin

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so] (posix,linux): call dlopen on [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so]

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so] failed (posix). dlerror: []

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so.1]

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so.1]: not found in map, open for the first time

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so.1] (posix): begin

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so.1] (posix,linux): call dlopen on [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so.1]

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so.1] failed (posix). dlerror: []

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so]

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so]: not found in map, open for the first time

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so] (posix): begin

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so] (posix,linux): call dlopen on [/home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so]

INFO         | Added library: /home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
INFO         | Selecting Vulkan device: SwiftShader Device (Subzero), Version: 1.3.0
initialize: Supports id properties, got a vulkan device UUID
INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [libGLESv2.so]: not found in map, open for the first time

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [libGLESv2.so] (posix): begin

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [libGLESv2.so] (posix,linux): call dlopen on [libGLESv2.so]

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [libEGL.so]: not found in map, open for the first time

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [libEGL.so] (posix): begin

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [libEGL.so] (posix,linux): call dlopen on [libEGL.so]

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [libX11]

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [libX11]: not found in map, open for the first time

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [libX11] (posix): begin

INFO         | SharedLibrary::open for [libX11] (posix,linux): call dlopen on [libX11.so]

INFO         | Initializing VkEmulation features:
INFO         |     glInteropSupported: false
INFO         |     useDeferredCommands: true
INFO         |     createResourceWithRequirements: true
INFO         |     useVulkanComposition: false
INFO         |     useVulkanNativeSwapchain: false
INFO         |     enable guestRenderDoc: false
INFO         |     ASTC LDR emulation mode: 2
INFO         |     enable ETC2 emulation: true
INFO         |     enable Ycbcr emulation: false
INFO         |     guestVulkanOnly: false
INFO         |     useDedicatedAllocations: false
INFO         | Graphics Adapter Vendor Google (Google Inc.)
INFO         | Graphics Adapter Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Google SwiftShader)
INFO         | Graphics API Version OpenGL ES 3.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0 SwiftShader 4.0.0.1)
INFO         | Graphics API Extensions GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 
INFO         | Graphics Device Extensions N/A
INFO         | Verified boot params were not found.
INFO         | Monitoring duration of emulator setup.
WARNING      | The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port
INFO         | Using security allow list from: /home/syammohan/development/AAOS/source/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib/emulator_access.json
WARNING      | *** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio ***
INFO         | The active JSON Web Key Sets can be found here: /run/user/1000/avd/running/5692/jwks/45bbfcd3-c041-4da2-9d2f-ea2b1cbbaec7/active.jwk
INFO         | Scanning /run/user/1000/avd/running/5692/jwks/45bbfcd3-c041-4da2-9d2f-ea2b1cbbaec7 for jwk keys.
INFO         | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: +token
INFO         | Advertising in: /run/user/1000/avd/running/pid_5692.ini
INFO         | Setting display: 0 configuration to: 320x480, dpi: 160x160 
INFO         | setDisplayActiveConfig 0
INFO         | Loading snapshot 'default_boot'...
INFO         | OpenGL Vendor=[Google (Google Inc.)]
INFO         | OpenGL Renderer=[Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Google SwiftShader)]
INFO         | OpenGL Version=[OpenGL ES 3.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0 SwiftShader 4.0.0.1)]
INFO         | Successfully loaded snapshot 'default_boot'
INFO         | OpenGL Vendor=[Google (Google Inc.)]
INFO         | OpenGL Renderer=[Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Google SwiftShader)]
INFO         | OpenGL Version=[OpenGL ES 3.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0 SwiftShader 4.0.0.1)]
INFO         | Wait for emulator (pid 5692) 20 seconds to shutdown gracefully before kill;you can set environment variable ANDROID_EMULATOR_WAIT_TIME_BEFORE_KILL(in seconds) to change the default value (20 seconds)

INFO         | Saving with gfxstream=1
INFO         | OpenGL Vendor=[Google (Google Inc.)]
INFO         | OpenGL Renderer=[Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Google SwiftShader)]
INFO         | OpenGL Version=[OpenGL ES 3.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0 SwiftShader 4.0.0.1)]

adb devices command log
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   offline


It's not clear which you prefer, goldfish emulator or cuttlefish emulator? You mixed the two in your question; in one case you used emulator command which is for goldfish, but then you mention running lunch aosp_cf ... which is for cuttlefish.
See https://source.android.com/docs/devices/cuttlefish for details on cuttlefish and https://source.android.com/docs/setup/test/avd for details of goldfish.

I have tried to install Cuttlefish, following https://source.android.com/docs/devices/cuttlefish/get-started. However, it shows [cannot access archive './cuttlefish-base_*64.deb] when I ran [sudo dpkg -i ./cuttlefish-base_*64.deb || sudo apt-get install -f]

Still not clear what you are trying to accomplish as an overall goal? If you want to play building and modifying AOSP I would suggest stick with goldfish emulator and avoid cuttlefish since cuttlefish is more complex. Check the first link: https://source.android.com/docs/setup/test/avd but note if working from the latest android code the lunch target is now sdk_phone64_x86_64-trunk_staging-userdebug.

I am trying to use an emulator from android studio now. As you suggested, I tried with glassfish itself with the suggested target. However now it is showing the below error
TARGET_PRODUCT=sdk_phone64_x86_64

HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-6.8.0-47-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-24.04.1-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
BUILD_ID=MAIN
OUT_DIR=out
09:52:07 ninja failed with: exit status 137
failed to build some targets (47 seconds)

Let's begin narrowing down the possible problems. If you start a regular emulator in Andorid Studio, not related to AOSP, does adb devices list it as online?

Yes, it is showing as online if I start a regular emulator(not related to AOSP) from Android Studio.
